# Trying sync data between Apple Watch and iOS app using App Groups and UserDefaults

Tags: ios, synchronization, watch, ios-app-group

I want to create a simple iOS app that syncs (and shares some data) with a watch app. I've tried to do this using AppGroup and UserDefaults. iOS app saves the data but the Apple Watch app can't read it. Does anyone know the reason? Can it be because of my free Development Account?

iOS code:

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print(FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.my.app")!
    .appendingPathComponent("switchState.plist"))

    var sharedDefault = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.my.app")

         sharedDefault?.set(textFieldOne.text, forKey: "shared1")
         print(UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.my.app")!.string(forKey: "shared1")!)
         sharedDefault?.synchronize()
}
```

iWatch code:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed() { 
let sharedDefault = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.my.app")
     print(FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.my.app")!
     .appendingPathComponent("switchState.plist"))
     print(UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.my.app")?.object(forKey: "shared1"))
     let sharedText = sharedDefault!.string(forKey: "shared1")
     textField.setText(sharedText)
     print(sharedText)
```

}

when I run iOS app - it writes to switchState.plist a key with value in a path: 
/Users/_userName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F5A0485A-CBB7-4903-8339-738DBE3491B6/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/5C371E82-27A7-4BB3-982D-B0E5CDE5AC52/Library/Preferences/switchState.plist

but when I try to read that data in iWatch app -

/Users/_userName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6F195AF7-73CA-4AF9-8CFE-5B47286F3DE5/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/533FEFB3-4A77-4A2B-8A53-99CF916D5481/

there is no plist file (return nil, of course)!

BUT! When I manually adds Library/Preferences/switchState.plist in second path - it works perfectly!

I've tried this on real devices - iWatch app says:

file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/D297CDB8-F623-4BDF-83D8-15505451EC92/switchState.plist
2020-03-04 10:59:25.736335+0200 IosWatchOsTest Extension[288:94115] [User Defaults] Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x16d92960> (Domain: group.com.sk.todoey-ios13.Todoey, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd

Can you help me with this?

Comment: You can't use an app group to share data between your iOS app and your watch app as they don't share a file system. You need to use the [WatchConnectivity framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and point out the right direction! I'll try to figure out this topic. Also, I've found this article https://medium.com/better-programming/watchconnectivity-swift-1f8cffb7c7a9 - it looks not so scary as apple docs:)